# ValueTuple set fields via reflection

Tags: c#, .net, tuples, valuetuple

I'm trying to set the fields of a ValueTuple at runtime using reflection and am having an issue. I suspect I'm not understanding something about how `FieldInfo.SetValue` works.

```
var a = (5, 5);
a.Item1 = 6;
Console.WriteLine(a.Item1); // 6

var t = a.GetType();
var f = t.GetField("Item1");
f.SetValue(a, 10);
Console.WriteLine(a.Item1); // 6 - Why not 10?
```

Any insight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're boxing the tuple when you pass it to `SetValue`, so it's setting a copy. If you box it via an `object` variable, pass that in, then unbox afterwards, you'll see the change. Here's a complete sample, adapting your code above:

```cs
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var a = (5, 5);
        a.Item1 = 6;
        Console.WriteLine(a.Item1); // 6

        var t = a.GetType();
        var f = t.GetField("Item1");
        object obj = a;
        f.SetValue(obj, 10);
        a = ((int, int)) obj;
        Console.WriteLine(a.Item1); // 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a technical reason FieldInfo.SetField and friends are not generic?

Comment: @MgSam: Firstly, they existed before generics did. But typically if you're doing reflection, that's because you don't know the type at compile-time - so the generic versions would rarely be useful, I suspect.

Comment: They did exist before generics- but certainly with .NET Core the opportunity existed to improve reflection APIs.

Comment: @MgSam: Not in terms of breaking changes, without making .NET Core adoption much, much harder.